# How to merge two dataframes based on a range of possible values in the second, but keep the values of the first?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

I'm merging two data frames through two columns using `merge`. Both data frames look so:

df1:

[image: df1]

df2:

[image: df2]

The goal is to merge all unique columns from df2 into df1 (in this case, only `Version`). The values of df2 represent a range in months, the `Month` value being the **final** Month for those values (i.e. for that version). In other words, df1 rows with Months 1 or 2 should have Version 1, Months 3 and 4 should have Version 2 and Month 5 should have Version 3.

I'm struggling with merging both data frames with this condition and thinking of ideas to match the values with a range. The actual code I'm working with has many more columns, so just mutating version into df1 won't do the trick. Sorry if I haven't been clear on anything. The amount of observations is also very, very large so efficiency in solving this is a factor. Both data frames are actually data.tables.

```
df1 <- data.frame("Type" = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"), "Month"=c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5), "Amount"=c(50,20,40,30,30,60,60,20,30,30,20,40,10,10,30,20))
df2 <- data.frame("Type" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), "Month"=c(2,4,5,2,4,5), "Version"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3))

data_merged <- merge(df, df2, all=TRUE, by=c("Type","Month"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `full_join` and `fill` the values with `.direction = "up"`

```
dplyr::full_join(df1, df2, by=c("Type","Month")) %>%
  tidyr::fill(everything(), .direction = 'up')

#   Type Month Amount Version
#1     A     1     50       1
#2     A     2     20       1
#3     A     2     40       1
#4     A     3     30       2
#5     A     3     30       2
#6     A     4     60       2
#7     A     4     60       2
#8     A     5     20       3
#9     B     1     30       1
#10    B     2     30       1
#11    B     3     20       2
#12    B     3     40       2
#13    B     4     10       2
#14    B     4     10       2
#15    B     4     30       2
#16    B     5     20       3
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, this worked! I had to change the direction from up to down since it was taking Month 2 to Version 2. Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo` after doing the `merge`

```
library(zoo)
transform(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), 
       Version = zoo::na.locf(Version, fromLast = TRUE))
#   Type Month Amount Version
#1     A     1     50       1
#2     A     2     20       1
#3     A     2     40       1
#4     A     3     30       2
#5     A     3     30       2
#6     A     4     60       2
#7     A     4     60       2
#8     A     5     20       3
#9     B     1     30       1
#10    B     2     30       1
#11    B     3     20       2
#12    B     3     40       2
#13    B     4     10       2
#14    B     4     10       2
#15    B     4     30       2
#16    B     5     20       3
```

Comment: Thank you akrun, this works! However, I need to add each unique column in that would otherwise be in na, and they're upwards of 20 columns such as "Version". It's a great solution for somebody looking to just fill in one or a couple of columns, though. Thank  you for your input!